# Python 3.x PPTX can't find placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, python-pptx

So my code is:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('template.pptx')

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Python 3.6 - Turtle Race"
subtitle.text = "Data Analytics&Visualization with random generated data"


for placeholder in prs.slide_layouts[4].placeholders:
    print('%d %s' % (placeholder.placeholder_format.idx, placeholder.name))

slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[4])
littleTitle = slide.placeholders[1]

littleTitle.text('Comparison of Winning times and pieces of wins')

prs.save("visualiztaion.pptx")
```

My output is(with the error):

```
0 Title 1
1 Text Placeholder 2
2 Content Placeholder 3
3 Text Placeholder 4
4 Content Placeholder 5
10 Date Placeholder 6
11 Footer Placeholder 7
12 Slide Number Placeholder 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!_!Piton/turtleRace/presentationMaker.py", line 34, in <module>
    littleTitle.text('Comparison of Winning times and pieces of wins')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myaSv.png)

You can see I have every recommended file in the project and if you want to I can send a picture of my project interpreter.

So my question is basically just how can I insert text into `0 Title 1` and into `1 Text Placeholder 2`.

So mostly I just want to solve and pass the error, because I have to make this code works.

So please help me out.

Comment: My guess is that littleTitle isn't what you think it is.  Try print(type(littleTitle)) before assigning the text and see what you have.

Comment: Have you worked through the User Guide in the documentation? https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html `Shape.text` is a property that returns a `str`; it is not a method. So you _assign_ to it to change its value, like `littleTitle.text = "Comparison of ..."`